# NoSuchMethodError StorageObject.getTimeCreated running job in Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to run a Spark job which works in local. It uses Google Storage. I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.services.storage.model.StorageObject.getTimeCreated()Lcom/google/api/client/util/DateTime;
    at com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo.fromPb(BlobInfo.java:798)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.Blob.fromPb(Blob.java:641)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.create(StorageImpl.java:139)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.create(StorageImpl.java:132)
...
```

Dataproc job is using `gcloud-java-storage-0.2.8.jar`, and I've tried both `google-api-services-storage-v1-rev62-1.21.0.jar` and `google-api-services-storage-v1-rev83-1.22.0.jar` without success, even though that method is defined. It looks like it's not using the right version of google-api-services-storage, but I don't know what I can do beyond uploading and specifying the jar.

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that the GCS connector built into Dataproc currently [compiles against an older](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/pom.xml#L205) `google-api-services-storage-v1` version. The `com.google.api.services.storage.model.StorageObject.getTimeCreated()` method was only added in a later version, so when the older version wins on the classpath, you hit the error. We'll likely update the version in a near future release, after validating full backwards compatibility.

In the meantime, you can either try to repackage the `com.google.api.services.storage.*` packages using the shade plugin in your own fatjar, the same way the GCS connector [repackages com.google.common.*](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/gcsio/pom.xml#L159) to avoid causing classpath collisions with users bringing their own Guava versions, or you can try to recompile the GCS connector yourself and swap it into your Dataproc cluster using an init action (you can basically copy/paste everything verbatim here except the first line where you need to supply a GCS bucket):

```
export GCS_BUCKET=[SOME BUCKET YOU OWN HERE WITHOUT gs:// PREFIX]


# Clone the code, update the dependency, build it
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop.git
cd bigdata-interop
sed -i "s/v1-rev35/v1-rev83/" pom.xml
mvn -P hadoop2 package


# Upload the new GCS connector to GCS
gsutil cp gcs/target/gcs-connector-1.5.3-hadoop2-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar gs://${GCS_BUCKET}/gcs-connector-1.5.3-hadoop2-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar


# Create a quick init action
cat << EOF > install_new_gcs.sh

#!/bin/bash
rm /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/gcs-connector-*.jar
gsutil cp gs://${GCS_BUCKET}/gcs-connector-1.5.3-hadoop2-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar \
    /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/
chmod 644 /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/gcs-connector-*.jar

EOF
gsutil cp install_new_gcs.sh gs://${GCS_BUCKET}/install_new_gcs.sh


# Create your dataproc cluster
gcloud dataproc clusters create ${USER}-new-connector \
    --initialization-actions gs://${GCS_BUCKET}/install_new_gcs.sh
```

Incidentally, since the root cause here is a collision between the automatically installed GCS connector for Hadoop with your own GCS libraries, you may want to consider using [Hadoop FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) interfaces in your code instead; in Dataproc this will be configured so that anywhere you pass a `Path`, you can use a path of the form `gs://bucket/foo/bar` and it'll automatically load the GCS connector libraries to just work. Your code would look something like this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

...
Path foo = new Path("gs://my-bucket/my-data.txt");
InputStream is = foo.getFileSystem(new Configuration()).open(foo);
...
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much, Dennis. I tried your instuctions to recompile and swap, and when I try to run a job I get this error: `=========== Cloud Dataproc Agent Error ===========
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.loadKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:84)
 at com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils.getCertificateTrustStore(GoogleUtils.java:76)
 at com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.java:55)`. Any clue?

Comment: I'm also trying with Hadoop FS, but job fails: `ExitCodeException exitCode=52: at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545) ...`. I'm still trying to debug down to Hadoop itself, but it seems related: if I run my job replacing writing with a simple stdout message it works.

Comment: Using `Path foo = new Path("gs://my-bucket/my-data.txt");` style finally worked for me, thanks!

Comment: @Dennis your workaround did work on my cluster, is there a fix planned on this ? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with 1.0 image version of Dataproc. I solved it by adding the following in my cluster init action:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/bigquery-connector-0.10.1-hadoop2.jar
rm /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/gcs-connector-1.6.0-hadoop2.jar

rm /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar
gsutil cp gs://my-bucket/jars/guava-18.0.jar /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/
```

Additionally, I built my Spark application jar as a fat jar, with the following maven configuration:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev97-1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigdataoss</groupId>
        <artifactId>gcs-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-hadoop2</version>
    </dependency>
```